# How to preserve the perception of angle between walls when the camera is rotating in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, camera

I am building a number of rooms with different shapes: Parallelogram, Rectangle, Rhombus, Square and etc. The viewer is supposed to look at the rooms from different corners, turn his head to right and left, and guess the shape of the room. So here “the perception of the angles between walls”  is very important. My problems are these:

1) most of the acute angles seem to be 90 degrees from the distance,

2) the angles between walls as well as the length of the walls seem to change when the viewer turns his head left or right.

As I have read until now, it is the consequence of using Perspective projection; however, with Orthogonal projection I would have no depth (no perception of depth) in the screen and since I am inside of the room, the size of the room should be bigger than clipped area which produces a quite rubbish image.

I just want to know that is there any way to avoid or at least minimize this deformation effect? Should I build my own projection (something between glortho and glprospective)?

It is also worth mentioning that I use "glutlookatfunction" for positioning the camera and lookat points . The eye position is always one of the room corners and the initial lookat point is the opposite corner of the viewer.By pressing right and left arrow keys , the lookat point moves on the imaginary circle serrounding the room , just like the most of the OpenGL programs I have seen until now .Do you think it would be better if I move the lookat point on the walls ? Or rotate the room instead of changing the look at point ?

I added some pictures for better illustration of my problem :

This is my parallelogram room :

[parallelogram.png](http://s16.postimage.org/nzswv5g4l/parallelogram.png)

As you can see here , the acute angle ,which is supposed to be 60 degrees ,seems to be at least 90 degrees . And this is my rectangle room, which doesn't give you the sense of being in a rectangle room at all :

[Rectangle.png](http://s8.postimage.org/vmlej8l45/Rectangle.png)

Comment: `most of the cute angels` Oh man, your project has cute angels?

Comment: Did you make sure that your projection matrix takes account of your display aspect ratio ? How do you construct your projection matrix ?

Comment: yes dude , I get the width and height of the screen by "glutget" function and calculate the aspect ratio , which is 1.25, for sending to "gluperspective(90,aspect,1.0,30.0)" . I Played with the value of far projection plane and reduced it from 100.0 to 30.0 (the room size is 20 X 10) but I didn't see any improvement .

Comment: Changing 'z far' will never have an impact on the field of view/distorsion of your projection matrix.

Comment: Also, try to use @<comment-author> as a header in your reply-comments, to notify the author of your response.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say, without seeing the problem in action, that your camera FOV is too large.

From your comment, your camera has a 112.5° horizontal FOV, which I believe introduces 'unnatural distortions' on the edges of the screen : simple OpenGL perspective projection is linear and suffers from too wide FOVs.

You may want to take a look at this [article](http://www.cambridgeincolour.com/tutorials/cameras-vs-human-eye.htm) comparing cameras to human eyes, as you want to jauge the perception of your users.

You should try to reduce the horizontal FOV of your camera, perhaps in the 80-90° range to see if it helps.

As a last resort, you could switch to [non-linear projections](http://paulbourke.net/miscellaneous/lenscorrection/), but you should make an educated choice before switching to this, there should be psychophysics research available (such as [this](http://wwwpsy.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/psychologie_institut_2/ae_lappe/freie_dokumente/steinicke_tvcg2010.pdf)) that may help you.

Comment: @<rotoglup> Thank you for your response , but unfortunately I could not achieve any improvement by reducing horizontal FOV . Maybe the pictures that I added to my post show my problem better.

Comment: @OmidRanjbar Indeed, the angles do not look right, but I'd be unable to say why, lack of lighting, lighting, shadows ? something else ? I must say that I don't know what matters for angle perception.

Comment: I did not use lighting , it seems to be a very basic problem .